# Is it possible to set a Row order policy for materialized views in Azure Data Explorer (ADX)?

Tags: azure, compression, kql, azure-data-explorer

Using a row order policy has significantly improved query time and compression factor for my non-materialized views. I'm considering applying the same policy to materialized views, but the ADX documentation doesn't indicate if this is supported for materialized views.

Can someone confirm that ADX does not support row order policy for materialized views? And what the logic behind not supporting it is?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-policies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is technically supported (though as you mentioned, not currently documented).

you can run, for example:

```
.alter materialized-view MyMaterializedView policy roworder (MyColumn asc)
```